# Angular 14 typed forms - how to have empty FormGroup initialized and type safety

Tags: angular, typescript

Recently i migrated one project from angular 13 to angular 14 and during the migration, i ended up using UntypedFormGroup because in a lot of places we were initializing the FormGroups with empty objects

```
form = new FormGroup({});
```

to

```
form = new UntypedFormGroup({});
```

the reason for that is because that form would be later assigned a value and I decided to first migrate to angular 14 and then think of a solution for those scenarios. So now I have to fix and use the typed FormGroups, however, there are too many places in that situation.

When I create the interfaces like this

```
form: MyFormType = new FormGroup({});
```

Typescript complains, saying that  **Type '{}' is not assignable to type '{ name: FormControl; }'**

So without removing the empty form initialization, how can I fix it? because if I remove the initialization, it could impact the application

Comment: you can assign to null at start  `form: MyFormType|null = null` and when data is ready you can assign it